# How to map arguments used in InvocationExpressionSyntax to formal parameters?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Say there is a method `int Compute(long id, string firstName, string secondName = "X") {...}`

This method can be invoked in a couple of different ways:

```
var x = Compute(1, "John", "Kowalski");
var x = Compute(1, "John");
var x = Compute(id: 1, secondName: "Kowalski", firstName: "John")
```

etc.

Is there a function within Roslyn that can map arguments used in InvocationExpressionSyntax to formal parameters used in function signature (same way as C# compiler does)?

Comment: As I know Roslyn doesn't have that function, but it can be easy written if you show a expected result this function for inputs that you are pointed out in the question.